# Referenced class library projects are not found when using AWS cdk to deploying a .NET6 lambda function

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, .net-6.0, dotnet-cli

I am trying to deploy a .NET6 based AWS Lambda function - "ABC.DynamoDBConnectLambda" using AWS CDK in Typescript. "ABC.DynamoDBConnectLambda" references two other custom class libraries - "ABC.Data" and "ABC.Services" which all live in the same "src" folder.

After running "cdk synth", I am getting the following error messages:

```
 Skipping project "/ABC.Data/ABC.Data.csproj" because it was not found.
 Skipping project "/ABC.Services/ABC.Services.csproj" because it was not found.
 Restored /asset-input/ABC.DynamoDBConnectLambda.csproj (in 26.49 sec).
    /var/lang/bin/sdk/6.0.201/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2065,5): warning : The referenced project '../ABC.Data/ABC.Data.csproj' does not exist. [/asset-input/ABC.Data/ABC.Data.csproj]
/var/lang/bin/sdk/6.0.201/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2065,5): warning : The referenced project '..//ABC.Services/ABC.Services.csproj' does not exist. [/asset-input/ABC.Services.csproj]
/var/lang/bin/sdk/6.0.201/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2065,5): warning : The referenced project '../Trustees.SFTPServices.Data/Trustees.SFTPServices.Data.csproj' does not exist.
```

Any help or suggestions would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I did some research and it seems to related to the command for publishing project, below is the dotnet cli that I run:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64 --self-contained -o /asset-output
```

Below is the complete cdk code I have:

```
const dynamoDbConnectLambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'dynamoDBEventHandler', {
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.DOTNET_6,
  timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(120),
  handler: 'bootstrap',
  code: lambda.AssetCode.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname,'../../src/Lambda.DynamoDBConnect'), {
    bundling: {
      image: lambda.Runtime.DOTNET_6.bundlingImage,
      command: [
        'bash', '-c',
        'export DOTNET_CLI_HOME=/tmp/DOTNET_CLI_Home && dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64 --self-contained -o /asset-output'
      ]
    }
  })
});
```

Below is the csproject file for lambda project - "ABC.DynamoDBConnect"

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <AWSProjectType>Lambda</AWSProjectType>
    <AssemblyName>bootstrap</AssemblyName>
    <!-- This property makes the build directory similar to a publish directory and helps the AWS .NET Lambda Mock Test Tool find project dependencies. -->
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- 
  When publishing Lambda functions for ARM64 to the provided.al2 runtime a newer version of libicu needs to be included
  in the deployment bundle because .NET requires a newer version of libicu then is preinstalled with Amazon Linux 2.
  -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == 'linux-arm64'">
    <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.AppLocalIcu" Value="68.2.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ICU.ICU4C.Runtime" Version="68.2.0.9" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.S3Events" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson" Version="2.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Core" Version="3.7.10.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2" Version="3.7.3.17" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ABC.Service.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ABC.Data.csproj" />
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem is in this line below: it only gets project - `Lambda.DynamoDBConnect` in the `src` folder, however, `ABC.Service` and `ABC.Data` are ignored since they all exist in the same level.

```
code: lambda.AssetCode.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname,'../../src/Lambda.DynamoDBConnect')
```

The solution is to update the code as below, so all projects are copied as they are, therefore, they can find each other.

```
code: lambda.AssetCode.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname,'../../src')
```

PS: there is a drawback for this solution, it copies everything in `src` folder, which means other un-needed projects that exist in the folder are also copied. This can cause performance issue that can be re-thinking about.